# How to estimate the order of n?

Tags: trigonometry

$$F_n= \left(\frac{m-2}{(m-1)^2-1}\right) \sum_{i=0}^n\{(m-1)^i \sum_{j=1}^i[2\sum_{k=0}^{n-j-1}\prod_{l=0}^k\left(\frac{\sin[(n-j-l)\theta]}{\sin[(n-j+2-l)\theta]}+1\right)]$$

i simply can't assume how to estimate the order of $n$ in this formula.According to other papers,the result should be $n^2$,but I can't figure out a useful way to estimate...

this formula comes from a paper talking about the mean first passage time of a network.this paper gives a universal formula,and this is this one...

Comment: May I ask a question ? Where did you catch the monster ? More serious, what is the context of this problem ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it actually comes from a paper i'm reading.it's about the calculation of hitting time of a network.

Comment: Is the paper (you have fun with) available online ? Just curious.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes.Are you interested in?I can send to you through email.

Comment: OK. You have my e-mail address in my profile. I hope it is a funny one (beside the monster) ! Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici hope you like it～

Comment: It was a loooooong time without such a fun !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici but I still have to read it....it's not a paper on math actually.